# Powershell and Port

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I need to connect to a database/SQL Instance from a remote server using PowerShell. Do I need an additional port number to be open on the server for communication or  can I use the default port of SQL 1433?

How does power shell communicate with SQL Server?

Are the ports required to be open between the source (PowerShell) server and SQL (SQL Server)?

Comment: This is a lot of basic questions. You should first go read some tutorials and/or books before you come asking those sort of questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to SQL Server remotely of course you need its port to be open.

The port can differ.

For the default instance it's 1433, for named instance it's dynamic by default and it's a SQL Server Browser to tell your underlying network library what the port is given the **name** of the instance.

In both cases whether it's a named or default instance the port can be reassigned manually to another port.

You can see the current port in use in SQL Server error log (in one of thefirst rows of the error log) or you can find it in Configuration Manager

Comment: The flow will be like this -> Powershell Connects to SQL Server ->  SQL Instance -> SQL Database ->                                                                         All this flow will be on port ? and there are chances that port for different database are different based on port defined by application team for there database.. so do i have to coordinate with app owners for there ports?

Comment: What do you want to say by your " that port for different database are different based on port defined by application team for there database"? There is no "port for every database defined by application team". One instance <-> one port (even if you can configure more ports for one instance, it's not related to DATABASE IN NO WAY)

Comment: Port is configured at the instance (server) level, not database level